# How do 'fake cell towers' work? And besides bugging and tracking what are they used for?

Tags: phone, cellular

A friend of mine used an app that detects suspicious cell towers and has been getting warnings today. He is worried about the possibility that someone may be specifically targeting him, which leads me to wonder how exactly these fake towers can be expected to work.

Will they actually target a specific number and intercept all calls made to/from that number discarding all non-targets? Or will they indiscriminately intercept all calls in a certain range?

And besides bugging cellphones and tracking their user's locations, what can these fake cell towers be used for? Are there any common schemes they are used in?

Comment: Did you do any research prior to posting this question? Here's a good summary on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_phone_tracker

Comment: Some interesting discussions of possible capabilities of fake cell towers here: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/11550/113999

Comment: @Sirens I did some but my search terms usually just ended up with news articles lol. Thanks for the link. This refers to a specific device though, there could be new models that operate differently for all I know.

Comment: I think that the term "stingray" is not a specific device, but refers to the class of devices.

Comment: BTW - what app is your friend using?

Comment: Think it's called Cell Spy Catcher

Comment: Nowadays cruise ships use them. So all the passengers can use their mobile phones to talk to each other (no outside connection, so it's free even when you're hundreds of miles away from any land).