# Fake bank text message

Tags: malware, mobile, banks, sms

I recently tried to use my card to buy something on my phone for £29.99. My card was declined so I used a different card and the payment went through.

A couple minutes later I get a message from a number, the same as my bank's, telling me "you've paid £29.99. if this is true send Y if not true send N" for the declined card. Since that wasn't true and the payment wasn't made on that card I sent N.

After speaking with the bank they told me it was not a legitimate text so they made me cancel my card. But is my phone hacked now that I've responded to the malicious text?

Comment: Replying to thetext did not hack your phone, but this entire episode suggests that your phone may have been hacked before you tried the payment.

Comment: Related answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/36613/184700

Answer (score 2):

Replying to an SMS message will not have infected your phone.

(I am assuming your phone is secure enough not to be infected by trivial means like displaying an SMS)